# Google App Engine Null Pointer Exception when trying to insert

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, localhost, google-cloud-endpoints

It seems as if the method from the endpoint class itself is not being called as none of the print statements I put in to debug gave any output

RELEVANT CODE

accessing the TransLogEndpoint class

```
        Translogendpoint.Builder builder = new Translogendpoint.Builder(
                 AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
                 null);         
        builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);
        Translogendpoint endpoint = builder.build();
```

I ended up hardcoding the object I wanted to insert

```
TransLog t=new TransLog();
t.setId(33);
t.setOperation("ins");
t.setTable("hisone");
t.setTransTime((long) 299221212);
t.setAcc("meh");
```

And tried to insert as such

```
try {
    endpoint.insertTransLog(t).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("could not insert Log");
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

This is how the endpoint method for inserting the TransLog looks I did not change any of its logic

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "insertTransLog")
 public TransLog insertTransLog(TransLog translog) {
    System.out.println("I am here");
    Key k=KeyFactory.createKey("TransLog",translog.getId());
    translog.setKey(k);
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
             if(containsTransLog(translog)) {
             throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.persist(translog);
        } finally {
              mgr.close();
        }
        return translog;
```

}

this is from the App Engine [Web Application Console]

```
 Jun 21, 2014 2:03:15 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod  
 INFO: cause={0}
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)
at com.example.agriexpensett.TransLogEndpoint.containsTransLog(TransLogEndpoint.java:154)
at com.example.agriexpensett.TransLogEndpoint.insertTransLog(TransLogEndpoint.java:101)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:127)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:85)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

and

```
Jun 21, 2014 2:03:15 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)
at com.example.agriexpensett.TransLogEndpoint.containsTransLog(TransLogEndpoint.java:154)
at com.example.agriexpensett.TransLogEndpoint.insertTransLog(TransLogEndpoint.java:101)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:127)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:85)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Could it be the lack of CamelCasing for the Class: Translogendpoint?

Comment: the actual class is named TransLogEndpoint but the way it's referenced by the GAE is a lowercase rep

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace says :

```
...
at com.example.agriexpensett.TransLogEndpoint.containsTransLog(TransLogEndpoint.java:154)
```

Maybe your issue is because the KeyFactory.createKey return a null value, so when it come to call containsTransLog, the method fire a NPE in containsTransLog.

I was able to fix this kind of issue by changing the default generated "contains..." method. 
So, you can try to change your containsTransLog method to take care of the NPE, by adding a check on your Key value :

```
@ApiMethod(name = "containsTransLog")
public boolean containsTransLog(TransLog translog) {
 if(translog.getKey() ==null)
        return false;
 EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();

 //...
}
```

You can also check if the value of "Key k" is null.

Hope this helps !